# Anyway to inverse factorial function?

Tags: python, algorithm

So the question comes like this, I'm new to python:

**def   factorial_cap(num):** For   positive    integer **n**,  the factorial   of  n   (denoted    as  **n!**),    is  the product 
of  all positive    integers    from    1   to  n   inclusive.      Implement   the function    that    returns the smallest
positive    n   such    that    n!  is  greater than    or  equal   to  argument    num.
o Assumption:   num will    always  be  a   positive    integer.

```
# Examples 
# factorial_cap(20) output is 4  since 3!<20 but 4!>20
# factorial_cap(24) output is 4 since 4!=24
# factorial_cap(1) output is 1 since 1!=1

# And here is what I got

def factorial_cap(num):
    n = 1
    for i in range (1,num+1):
        n = n*i
```

I'm pretty sure this is the right function for factorial def. But I just couldn't figure out, instead of getting the 'total value', how can I just get the right output as I posted example above?

Btw, should I use 'return' at the end of def, or it does not matter in this case?

Comment: Try using a `return n` after the for loop. Also in your loop, change `range(1, num+1)` to `range(2, num+1)`, you don't have to multiply the number by 1 again.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Of course it is.

Comment: Btw you can use Stirling approximation for "invertion of factorial": http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61755/is-there-a-way-to-solve-for-an-unknown-in-a-factorial?rq=1

Comment: Yes, `return n` is very important.  It's like Webster writing down a definition for a word, but not putting it in a dictionary.  If you don't return it, `n` is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There needs to be a test for when the current total is greater than or equal to the requested number. So you can use the condition of a while loop to perform that check, and increment a counter, `i`, that keeps track of the current iteration. Then it's a matter of returning the current value of `i` that produced the value >= the required number:

```
def factorial_cap(num):
    n = 1
    i = 1
    while n < num:
        i += 1   
        n *= i
    return i

>>> factorial_cap(20)
4
>>> factorial_cap(24)
4
>>> factorial_cap(25)
5
>>> factorial_cap(1)
1
>>> factorial_cap(3628800)
10
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a return but that isn't `n`, but `i`

```
def factorial_cap(num):

    n = 1
    i = 0

    while True:

        i += 1
        n = n*i
        if n >= num:
            break

    return i

print(factorial_cap(20))
print(factorial_cap(24))
print(factorial_cap(1))
```